# Maven compile all source files, but include into jar only few of them

Tags: maven

I have source folder with more than 500 source files. 
I need to produce 4 Jars from this sources.
But there is one problem when i try to compile sources needed for my first jar they dont want to compile because, all sources are needed to compile my specific sources.

and here is the question: if i compiled once all my 500 source files with maven how i can split them into several JAR files? i dont need that all my for 4 jar were containing all 500 sources, each JAR must contain only their specific .class files...

With ant it was very easy, u just compile all sources once, and then when creating JAR u just include specified .class files into jar, and no problem... Can some thing similar be done i n MAVEN?

Answer (score 4):

You should split your source code in multiple inter-dependant java projects.

Then, make each project compile to a jar.

Comment: Spliting the source code is a bad idea, in this project i have only 500, but next project include over 1200+ and spliting them by hands is a bad idea

Comment: Maybe you can explain more why you need 4 jars, and why a project by jar isn't a good option for you...? Because it's a very standard way to split sources.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that this is split into suitable smaller modules that can be shared

Comment: Splitting project by hand, or creating include/exclude regex for this project to generate 4 diffrent jars are equal hard. But after splitting the project is proper and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend going Tristans solution but you should also achieve what you want by configurating the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) to exclude/include the content that you (not) want. This is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) (see *How to include/exclude content from jar artifact?*).

As you can only build one artifact with one pom.xml (in general) you have to prepare several pom's (or you try the `<classifier>` configuration also described on the maven-jar-plugin Usage page (I never used it but it seams to help you to do what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD split this jar project into Multi-Module jar project. This will solve your problem and project structure will be much better.